# Convert Date datatype from SQL Server to ToShortDateString in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to convert the date output to a `ToShortDateString` in my text box from a `DataTable`. Currently it's showing "2/4/1965 12:00:00 AM".

Here's the code:

```
 txtDOB.text = dataTable.Rows[0][7].ToString().Trim();
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the data type of the column onece it's in you dataTable not your database (DateTIme, String)?

Comment: DateTime  "Date {2/4/1965 12:00:00 AM} System.DateTime"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DataRow` extension method `Field` to cast it to the correct type `DateTime`. Then you can use `DateTime.ToShortDateString`:

```
txtDOB.text = dataTable.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>(7).ToShortDateString();
```

You can also use `DateTime.ToString`:

```
txtDOB.text = dataTable.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>(7).ToString("d");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime Temp = (DateTime) dataTable.Rows[0][7]
txtDOB.text = Temp.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a direct cast first:

```
var date = (DateTime)dataTable.Rows[0][7];
txtDOB.Text = date.ToShortDateString();
```

If the database is storing the field as an actual date, that is the best way to get it back.

Comment: Man, I didn't even think of casting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 string date = dataTable.Rows[0][7].ToString().Trim();
 txtDOB.text = date.Split(' ')[0];
```